# Alamofire post request for image upload giving status code- 400 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, http-status-code-400

I am trying to upload image to server, but my code sometimes uploads the image and sometimes don't and gives a Status = 400 and says failed to upload file. Can you guys check that out why my code give me this error. And i note it gives me this error sometimes.
Here is the postman requirements:[Postman Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyrjQ.png).And here is the Status = 400 response:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8dGL.png).
Here is my code:

```
func UPLOD(){
    let image  = myImageView.image
    let serviceName = "http://192.168.80.21:8800/api/v1/upload/uploadfile"
    
    var parameters = [String: Any]()
    parameters["Folder"] = "uploadfile"
    parameters["Filename"] = "demo3\(self.currentTimeStamp)"
    parameters["Ext"] = "jpeg"
    parameters["FileToUpload"] = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
    
    guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accesstoken") else {
        return
    }
    print("Create button ACCESS KEY::::- \(token)")
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "x-access-token": token,
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    ]
    
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData:MultipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if key == "FileToUpload" {
                multipartFormData.append(
                    value as! Data,
                    withName: key,
                    fileName: "demo3\(self.currentTimeStamp)",
                    mimeType: "image/jpeg"
                    //_img.jpg
                )
            } else {
                multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }}},
    to: serviceName, method: .post, headers: headers) { (encodingResult:SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) in
        switch encodingResult {
        
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.result.value!)
                        }
            upload.responseJSON { [self] response in
                
                if let Response = response.result.value as? [String : Any],
                   let myData = Response["data"] as? [String : Any],
                   let imgPath = myData["status"] {
                    imageUrl = imgPath as! String
                    print(imageUrl)
                    print("ImagePath --> ", imgPath)
                    responseURL = imageUrl
                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    defaults.setValue(imageUrl, forKey: "imageURL")
                    let key = defaults.object(forKey: "imageURL")
                    print(key as Any)
                    self.alamofireRequest(requestURL: "http://192.168.80.21:3204/api/product/create")
                }
                if let data = response.result.value {
                    let _ = JSON(data)
                }
            }
            break
            
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are running your own server ("http://192.168.80.21:8800/api/v1/upload/uploadfile"). What are the server logs regarding the error?

Comment: i have no idea about server logs, sorry, can you demonstrate? please